# How to bind display menuitem to a static text

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am trying to create a form, which can mimic the functionality of an area page, at least it should display links to other forms (if categorization cannot be done) how can i achieve it?

Can i bind a menu item to a static text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using .net's link label, unfortunately did not see Matej's answer, but will give it a try when I will actually build this for client, here is what I created:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Create *Tab* within form

   - change `Style` to `FastTabs`
   - change `Width` to `Column width`
   - change `Height` to `Columnt height`
2. Add *TabPage* to Tab
3. Drag MenuItem to Tab (or add *MenuItemButton*)

   - change `Style` to `Link`

XPO: [AreaPageSimulation](https://gist.github.com/matejskubic/1eea3f8e1ca948c077b2#file-_areapagesimulation_-xpo)

[image: Area Page Form simulatuion]